# SQL query not working due syntax error at or near "COLLATE"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is the query I'm trying to run.

When I run it I get the following error:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "COLLATE" Position:
> 151

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

```
select iusum.sf_uid as numeric_id, institution_user.*
from institution_user
join institution_user_sf_user_mapping iusum
  on institution_user.user_id COLLATE utf8_general_ci = iusum.user_id
where institution_id = "6afc2d2c-ec90-455f-88bd-b6678b94be75"
```

Comment: Note that double quotes are for (delimited) identifiers. Use single quotes for string literals.

Comment: What does `select version()` give you? Did you [create](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcollation.html) a collation with that name?

Answer (score 0):

such a collation doesn't exist, you need something like this, which only works for Postgres Version since 10

Maybe you are searching for `Ilike`

> The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension.

Which will also for earlier versions

```
CREATE tABLE institution_user(user_id varchar(10),institution_id varchar(36))
```

```
CREATE TABLe institution_user_sf_user_mapping(user_id varchar(10))
```

```
SELECT * 
from institution_user 
  join institution_user_sf_user_mapping iusum 
    on institution_user.user_id COLLATE "en_US" = iusum.user_id 
where institution_id = '6afc2d2c-ec90-455f-88bd-b6678b94be75'
```

| user_id | institution_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/L3fQe97Y)

Comment: Note that OP gets a _syntax_ error. Must be using an ancient Postgresql version.

Comment: The error will also occur in postgres 15, you can like horse, suggested define such a collation, but it will not work, the way op intended, so i am not really sure of he has a much older Version

Comment: Postgresql 15 will give a "collation does not exist" error instead of a syntax error.

Comment: Postgres 9.6 has the same error  https://dbfiddle.uk/b-eXZvNV

Comment: Then OP must be using a very, very old Postgresql version.

Comment: Thank you so much to both for your help. I'm not able to test it yet but will mark the answer as soon as i can.